# Unity3d: Find which gameObject is in front

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, vector, position

I have two `gameObjects` `A` and `B`. They are `rotated` at `90 degrees`, which makes its `local y axis` face forward.

**1st Case**

[image]

In this case, the `local y position of B` is ahead of `local y position of A`

**2nd Case**

[image]

Even though their global position is same as the 1st case, we can observe here that `local y position of A` is ahead of `local y position of B`.

I tried using `A.transform.localPosition.y` and `B.transform.localPosition.y` to find which is greater but it doesnt work. What can I do to find which is front in these two different cases?

Answer (score 1):

Vector projections are your friend here. Project both positions onto a line and compare their magnitude (or square magnitude, it's faster).

Case 1:

```
Vector3 a = Vector3.Project(A.position, Vector3.up);
Vector3 b = Vector3.Project(B.position, Vector3.up);
if (a.sqrMagnitude > b.sqrMagnitude)
{
    // a is ahead
}
else
{
    // b is ahead
}
```

Case 2: Project both positions onto Vector3.left.

Maybe you can even always simply project the two positions onto one of the two objects' forward vector (A.forward or B.forward assuming they're rotated equally).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could compare `Vector3.Dot(A.position, A.forward)` and `Vector3.Dot(B.position, B.forward)` to find the one in front in relation to their forward.
The object with the bigger [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) is in front, and this works in all rotations, including 3D ones.

You can use the following snippet to test for yourself:

```cs
// Assign these values on the Inspector
public Transform a, b;
public float RotationZ;

void Update() {
    a.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, RotationZ);
    b.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, RotationZ);

    Debug.DrawRay(a.position, a.right, Color.green);
    Debug.DrawRay(b.position, b.right, Color.red);

    var DotA = Vector2.Dot(a.position, a.right);
    var DotB = Vector2.Dot(b.position, b.right);

    if (DotA > DotB) { Debug.Log("A is in front"); }
    else { Debug.Log("B is in front"); }
}
```